# onSearchRequested() isn't call when I show dialog?

Tags: android

I implement search box, to be displayed only on main activity(and on search activity by default). And it works. But I want to disable opening search box(long press menu button) when user from menu open some dialog.

In onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) I have in one case statement:
`isDirection=true;
showDialog(ROUTE_DIALOG);`

In onSearchRequested() I have:
`alert("Search");  // show Toast
if(isDirection) return false;
else return super.onSearchRequested();`

When I long press menu button I see Toast "Search" and searh box, but when I open Dialog by pressing menu item and than long press menu I don't see Toast "Search" but search box opens. Where is the problem? onSearchRequested() isn't called when dialog is opened?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us your code.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/cf600fd7efc5de0b/7099d09127b42448?lnk=gst&q=onSearchRequested#7099d09127b42448